# document library with document set views (how to change)

Tags: document-set, document-library

I have a document library which has document sets.  Is it possible to have the view (columns) that is displayed when you first navigate to the document library different than the view/columns that are displayed once you click on a particular document set?

My document set contains a content type (with columns) and these columns really don't have values when viewing the document library from the top.  The columns are visible however they do not contain values because the document set itself doesn't have values for those fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OOTB the views are the same when displaying the list of document sets and displaying one document set with all the files in it. But you can set different views:

1. Create a new view to use when displaying the files in the document set
2. Go to the list settings and allow management of content types in Advanced Settings
3. Select the Document Set contenttype
4. In the next screen select Document Set settings
5. Select your newly created view at the Welcome Page View section
6. Press Ok

Now the default All Documents view will be shown when displaying all the document sets and the newly created view will be displayed when viewing one document set with the files within.

Answer (score 0):

You can cutomize "welcome page" for document set.